# Using django-registration-redux, but nothing happen

Tags: python, django

`tangowithdjango` chapter12, the author teach me to use `django-registration-redux` to achieve login and registration function. But i found it just don't work. It means that,  i could not use this to login and register. And i just follow the steps the author told me.

here's my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
# Create your views here.

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return '/search/'


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^search/', include('search_engine.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django_comments',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
)

REGISTRATION_OPEN = True
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DATS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/search/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

And i also have three html files, including `templates/account/base.html`, `templates/registration/login.html` and `templates/registration/registration_form.html`

My login.html

```
<form method="post" role="form" class="form-signin" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group border" style="width: 300px">
                        <label for="id_username" class="sr-only">用户名</label>
                        <input class="form-control border" style="border-top-width: medium;" id="id_username" width="200px" maxlength="35" name="username" type="text" placeholder="请输入您的用户名" />
                        <label for="id_password" class="sr-only">密码</label>
                        <input class="form-control border" style="border-bottom-color: #f49f00;" id="id_password" name="password1" type="password" placeholder="请输入您的密码" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin: 4% 0 0 0; width: 300px; border-radius: 2px;background-color: #1a274b; color: white; " type="submit">登录</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: 'just don't work' isn't very helpful. What does happen? What error do you get?

Comment: @alasdair what i mean is that, i could not use `django-registration-redux` to login and register. When i click the button, it didn't redirect to `/search/`, and it just stop in the same page, such as login page and register page.

Comment: What does happen when you click the button? Does your browser submit the form (if so, what url does it submit to)? Do you get form errors?

Answer (score 0):

Your template is too complicated. Start with the [template from the tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/login_redux.html#login-template), and get that working first.

```
{% extends "rango/base.html" %}

{% block body_block %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>

    <p>Not  a member? <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Register</a>!</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Then, once the view is working, you can customise the template if required. Remember to include the form's errors, which you are not currently doing. See the docs on [rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) for more information.